# How to record an inkCanvas, save inkcanvas as animation or video?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, inkcanvas

using C#, I want to save what the user draw in an ink canvas as an animation or video, just like the iPad app [Show Me](http://www.showme.com)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16579/Saving-Rebuilding-InkCanvas-Strokes

Comment: Do you want to save a frame for each stroke being added?  Or save multiple frames for each time the mouse moves?  Normally when a new stroke is added it doesn't raise an event until the user lifts the mouse and finishes the stroke.

Comment: @Moozhe doesn't matter, I need the final effect of recording

Comment: @Moozhe may be by each stroke, I guess it will give the recording effect stroke/frame